# Coordinates on quotient manifold $\mathrm{SO}(3)/\Gamma$

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, topological-groups, group-actions, quotient-space

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Say I have coordinates for $\SO(3,\mathbb{R})$, e.g., a parametrization by Euler angles. Is there a reasonable way to *explicitly* prescribe coordinates on the quotient manifold $\SO(3,\mathbb{R})/\Gamma$ where $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup?

Comment: Very neat question. A more general question is if I have a matrix Lie group $G$, e.g. $G=SO(3)$, what is a "good" way to parameterize $G/\Gamma$? My guess is to use non-square matrices, as many quotient manifolds of Lie groups are parameterized with them.

Comment: For $SO(3)$, the finite subgroups (up to conjugacy) are just the cyclics, the dihedrals, and the symmetry groups of the Platonic solids.  I believe the first two cases are relatively straightforward with Euler angles, which leaves only the Platonic cases (I think there are three of these because of duality).  Here it is perhaps easiest to work in $SU(2)$ - later reducing via the double-covering projection to $SO(3)$ - and use generating matrices in $SU(2)$ for the lifts of the subgroups.  (See e.g. https://leuschke.org/uploads/McKay-total.pdf)